# VK Observer - Какой виджет был нажат?

Tags: javascript, html, vkontakte-api, события

Здравствуйте!

Есть страница с большим количеством VK-виджетов "Мне нравится".
У каждого виджета свой "page_id" и "page_url". Их код выглядит так:

```
<div id="vk_like_1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Like("vk_like_1", {type: "button", pageURL: "http://someurl.com"}, 'like_widget_id_1');
</script>
```

VK API предоставляет так называемый VK Observer для отслеживания действий с виджетом. Конкретно перехватить событие лайка нужно так:

```
VK.Observer.subscribe("widgets.like.liked", function f()
{
    alert ('Я лайкнул');
});
```

Работает. Только у меня кнопок "Мне нравится" около десятка на странице.

Каким образом можно узнать, с помощью **какого** виджета был поставлен лайк. Ну или как-то узнать хотя бы **id** блока где был поставлен лайк.

Comment: Может так: `VK.Observer.subscribe("widgets.like.liked", function f()
{
    alert ($(this).attr('id'));
});` ? Было бы легче, если бы вы показали полный код кнопки лайка

Comment: К сожалению, такой способ не сработал. Вывел undefined.
Да собственно это и есть полный код кнопки.

Comment: CMTV, а если просто взять и отследить на какой элемент был произведён клик? Если нужно, могу добавить в ответ, как отследить

Comment: @Yuri, можно конечно и так, однако чисто гипотетически клик это не лайк и это может вызвать ошибки или проблемы (например по какой-то причине лайк не поставился, а клик был засчитан).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что на запрос ВКонтакте мне ответили отрицательно:

> Здравствуйте, Пётр!
>
> Простите за долгое ожидание.
>
> К сожалению, на данный момент реализацию Вашей идеи никак не
>   осуществить. Разработчики пообещали сделать, чтобы обсервер принимал
>   параметр page_id.
>
> Команда ВК.

Но я нашел способ. На данный момент - 18.02.2017 - VK Observer при событии лайка возвращает не один (как указано в документации), два параметра: `likes_num` и `vk_widget_num`.

```
VK.Observer.subscribe("widgets.like.liked", function f(likes_num,vk_widget_num) {
       /* ... */
});
```

Первый параметр `likes_num` содержит количество лайков у текущего виджета. Все как положено.

Второй параметр `vk_widget_num` содержит число уже загруженных виджетов на странице (виджет "Мне нравится", "Комментарии", "Это интересно" и т.д.). Другими словами VK вторым параметром передает вам какой по счету (начиная с 1) этот виджет будет на странице.

**===== Решение задачи**

Для начала добавим дополнительный атрибут к HTML тегам:

```
<div id="widget_1" class="like_widget" data-widget-number="1"></div>
<script>VK.Widgets.Like("widget_1", {type: "vertical", pageURL: 'url_1'}, 1);</script>

<div id="widget_1" class="like_widget" data-widget-number="2"></div>
<script>VK.Widgets.Like("widget_2", {type: "vertical", pageURL: 'url_2'}, 2);</script>
```

Теперь регистрируем наш обработчик события `widgets.like.liked`:

```
VK.Observer.subscribe("widgets.like.liked", function f(likes_num,vk_widget_num)
{
    var widget_id = $('.like_widget[data-widget-number=' + vk_widget_num + ']').attr('id');

    alert ("Вы лайкнули! Был нажат виджет с ID: " + widget_id + ". Количество лайков: " + likes_num);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно так:

```
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="like" id="a">A</div>
<div class="like" id="b">B</div>
<div class="like" id="c">C</div>
<div class="like" id="d">D</div>

<!-- JS -->

var liked = 0;
VK.Observer.subscribe("widgets.like.liked", function f() {
  liked = 1;
});
$('.like').click(function() {
  if(liked == 1){
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
  };
});
```

Comment: Это могло бы сработать, да вот только нельзя вешать на iframe события типа "click". А виджет "Мне нравится" как раз и есть iframe...

Answer (score 0):

1. Положи каждый виджет в обертку с уникальным id.
2. Сохраняй где-нибудь, с какой из оберток пользователь взаимодействовал в последний раз. Это может быть, например, событие mouseenter или раскрытия дропдауна с твоим виджетом.

Теперь внутри обработчика события лайка можешь с помощью этого id определять, с помощью какого виджета был поставлен лайк.

Вот примерная реализация, нужно только дополнительно хранить id элемента, на котором произошло событие mouseenter.  (скопировал отсюда https://gist.github.com/jaydson/1780598)

```
var myConfObj = {
  iframeMouseOver : false
}
window.addEventListener('blur',function(){
  if(myConfObj.iframeMouseOver){
    console.log('Wow! Iframe Click!');
  }
});

document.getElementById('YOUR_CONTAINER_ID').addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
   myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = true;
});
document.getElementById('YOUR_CONTAINER_ID').addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
    myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = false;
});
```

Правда, у тебя могут возникнуть проблемы с мобильными устройствами, т.к. у них нет ховера. В этом случае попробуй адаптировать вот это решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript/23231136#23231136